# erlang response http request in decimal instead of letter

Tags: rest, http, post, erlang, cowboy

I'm beginning using Erlang with Cowboy and Leptus to create a REST API.

So I just tried something simple:

*myapp_handler.erl*

```
-module(myapp_handler).
-compile({parse_transform, leptus_pt}).
-export([init/3]).
-export([cross_domains/3]).
-export([terminate/4]).
-export([post/3]).

%% Cross Domain Origin
%% It accepts any host for cross-domain requests
cross_domains(_Route, _Req, State) ->
   {['_'], State}.

%% Start
init(_Route, _Req, State) ->
  {ok, State}.

post("/myRequest", Req, State) ->

  Json = "[
    {
      \"test\": \"hello\"
    }
  ]",

  {200, {json, Json}, State}.

%% End
terminate(_Reason, _Route, _Req, _State) ->
   ok.
```

After launching the server, I tried to run the POST request through curl:

> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/myRequest --header
>   "Content-Type:text/json"

And the answer of the request is:

```
[91,10,32,32,32,32,123,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,116,101,115,116,34,58,32,34,104,101,108,108,111,34,10,32,32,32,32,125,10,32,32,93]
```

All the numbers are the value of the character in decimal from the ascii table. But I wonder why does the answer of the request is displayed in numbers instead of letters. Did I do something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Leptus before, but, let's take a look at an example REST endpoint from their README on Github (https://github.com/s1n4/leptus):

```
get("/", _Req, State) ->
  {<<"Hello, leptus!">>, State};

get("/hi/:name", Req, State) ->
  Status = ok,
  Name = leptus_req:param(Req, name),
  Body = [{<<"say">>, <<"Hi">>}, {<<"to">>, Name}],
  {Status, {json, Body}, State}.
```

It appears that if you post a tuple of `{json, Term}` it will automatically convert your Erlang term to JSON. So instead of making your JSON manually you could instead use:

```
post("/myRequest", Req, State) ->
  Json = [{<<"test">>, <<"hello">>}],
  {200, {json, Json}, State}.
```

It also appears that Leptus is expecting your strings and JSON keys and JSON string values to be passed in as binaries. So if you wanted to return a simple string of output you would use the following:

```
post("/myRequest", Req, State) ->
  {200, <<"hello">>, State}.
```

Typically libraries will use binaries instead of standard Erlang strings because binaries are more efficient than Erlang string lists.

Comment: Thank for you answer it works ! I've another question, when you want to put an array of objects in JSON literal? How can I achieve this? For example: 
```Json = [
  {
    <<"hello">>, <<"test">>,
    [
      {
        {<<"a">>, <<"b">>},
        {<<"c">>, <<"d">>},
        {<<"e">>, <<"f">>},
        {<<"g">>, <<"h">>}
      }
    ]
  }
],```
But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its probably converting proplists to JSON objects. Try `Json = [[{<<"hello">>, <<"test">>}], [{<<"a">>, <<"b">>}, {<<"c">>, <<"d">>}, {<<"e">>, <<"f">>}, {<<"g">>, <<"h">>}]]`.

Comment: I had an error while executing my route with your code: `Ranch listener leptus_http had connection process started with cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at <0.162.0> exit with reason: {{nocatch,{error,invalid_ejson}},[{jiffy,encode,2,[{file,"src/jiffy.erl"},{line,34}]},{leptus_handler,prepare_headers_body,2,[{file,"src/leptus_handler.erl"},{line,411}]},{leptus_handler,handle_response,5,[{file,"src/leptus_handler.erl"},{line,390}]},{leptus_handler,upgrade,4,[{file,"src/leptus_handler.erl"},{line,82}]},{cowboy_protocol,execute,4,[{file,"src/cowboy_protocol.erl"},{line,529}]}]}
`  Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like leptus is using jiffy for encoding (https://github.com/davisp/jiffy). Jiffy appears to expect the Erlang JSON equivalent to be a single element tuple containing a proplist (`{proplist()}`). Try this: `{[{[{<<"hello">>, <<"test">>}]}, {[{<<"a">>, <<"b">>}, {<<"c">>, <<"d">>}, {<<"e">>, <<"f">>}, {<<"g">>, <<"h">>}]}]}`.

Comment: According to an Erlang mailing list discussion, it appears that the single element tuple was used to simplify pattern matching Erlang JSON representation vs a list. Here is a link to the discussion: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-July/074756.html.

Answer (score 3):

Erlang strings are lists of integers, so what you got back is exactly what you are supposed to (well, this kind of data might be binary strings or list strings, actually). The weird thing about looking at responses in the shell is what the shell thinks is the appropriate way to format output: as a string or as a list. If there are any ASCII "control" characters, or values greater than 127, and it doesn't think its in a UTF-8 locale, then it will just print integers.

Usually you can be pretty sure to get the characters if you do:

```
Response = your_function(YourArgs),
io:format("Response:~ts~n", [Response]).
```

instead of just relying on the shell to format output to stdio the default way (which always falls back to a list of integers if anything is the slightest bit uncertain about the environment).

Pasting your output into my shell...

```
1> Z = [91,10,32,32,32,32,123,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,116,101,115,116,34,58,32,34,104,101,108,108,111,34,10,32,32,32,32,125,10,32,32,93].                                                       
"[\n    {\n      \"test\": \"hello\"\n    }\n  ]"
2> io:format("Using ~~ts:~n~ts~n~n"                                                 
2>           "Using ~~tw:~n~tw~n~n"
2>           "Using ~~tp:~n~tp~n~n",
2>           [Z, Z, Z]).
Using ~ts:
[
    {
      "test": "hello"
    }
  ]

Using ~tw:
[91,10,32,32,32,32,123,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,116,101,115,116,34,58,32,34,104,101,108,108,111,34,10,32,32,32,32,125,10,32,32,93]

Using ~tp:
"[\n    {\n      \"test\": \"hello\"\n    }\n  ]"

ok
```